# return mysql data from module to app.js using nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, module

I am newbie in node.js and I'm sorry for my silly question.

I want to separate and organize my app for easy working with files. For this reason I create a module to do my mysql database there but I have problem with module.I can't return module data to use in my main js file `app.js`

console shows `undefined` and browser shows nothing

here is my code

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
// app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: 'database'
});
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var User = require('./models/userModels');
var bookRouter = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

bookRouter.route('/books')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            // console.log(book);
            // res.send(book);
        })
        .get(function (req, res) {
            res.send(User.allUsers); // <--- shows nothing
            console.log(User.allUsers); //<--- returned undefined
        });

app.use('/api', bookRouter);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome to my API');
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Running on PORT via gulp  ' + port);
});
```

**userModels.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "luxa"
});

module.exports = {
    allUsers: con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log(result); // return result correctly
            // return result; 
            callback(err, result); // Error
        });
    }),
};
```

what's my problem?

Comment: What is inside of `userModels`?

Comment: @LEQADA sorry that was a mistake in `userModule.js` in fact that is `userModel.js` I edit the code

Comment: Looks like there is still a mistake. Filename is `userModel`, but you import `userModels`

Comment: @LEQADA yes that was a mistake again, I correct the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I see a lot of wrong code here. Let's have a look on this part:

```
allUsers:   con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // console.log(result); // return result correctly
            // return result; 
            callback(err , result); // Error
        });
    }) ...
```

First I can say that this is not a correct function declaration. And also I see that finally you are calling `callback(err , result);` but **callback** is coming from nowhere ... So the previous code could look like this:

```
allUsers: function (callback) {
    con.connect(function (err1) {
        if (err1){
            /* use return to prevent the code to continue */
            return callback(err1, null);
        }
        con.query("SELECT * FROM users", function (err2, result, fields) {
            if (err2){
                return callback(err2, null);
            }
            callback(err2, result); 
        });
    });
}
```

Now lets have a look on this part of your code:

```
.get(function (req , res) {
    res.send(User.allUsers); // <--- shows nothing
    console.log(User.allUsers); //<--- returned undefined
})
```

Basically when doing `User.allUsers` you are doing nothing but passing the function itself. If you want to call function use `()`, so `User.allUsers()` is the right code, but this code is asynchronous and you will get nothing again ... Now comes the part to use the `callback`. So previous code can look like this:

```
.get(function (req, res) {
    /* the code is async so first obtain the data then use res.send() */
    User.allUsers(function (err, results) {
        res.send({
            error: err, /* here you should have any error if it happens */
            results: results /* here you should have your results */
        });
    });
})
```

Check and see if the code is clear to you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks, That worked correctly and sorry for my question, I start learning from Sunday and my mistakes are stupid. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome, I hope you will get a better understanding of javascript and learn new things. I'm glad that this code works for you :) Good Luck!